# where do I find the definition of class objects in spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

I would like to know what kind of information an object of class `Spatialpolygons` has versus an object of class `Polygons`.

Comment: Any reason you cannot read the source code?

Comment: Have you tried investigating the two with the `str()` command?

Answer (score 2):

If you open help pages for `Polygon` or `SpatialPolygons` (doesn't really matter, it will lead you to the same page), you can click on `SpatialPolygons-class` and `Polygons-class` links. There, you can see which slots each class contains.

`Polygon-class` as an example:

```
Slots

ringDir:
    Object of class "integer"; the ring direction of the ring (polygon) coordinates, holes are expected to be anti-clockwise 
labpt:
    Object of class "numeric"; an x, y coordinate pair forming the label point of the polygon 
area:
    Object of class "numeric"; the area of the polygon 
hole:
    Object of class "logical"; does the polygon seem to be a hole 
coords:
    Object of class "matrix"; coordinates of the polygon; first point should equal the last point
```